# Can not open Work Item from URL

Tags: tfs

TFS 2012 and User with Limit Access to Team Web  Access.
This User can create Work Item and change it from project page, but he cannot open this Work Item from such url:

```
http://servername:8080/tfs/web/wi.aspx?pcguid={collectionguid}&id={workitemid}
```

It opens the page with error:
TF400409:You do not have licensing rights to access this feature: Standard Features

Why user can not open his Work Item from such url?

Answer (score 0):

While the message itself is more or less self-explanatory, you could try to use the web access URL instead of the API web page:

```
http://servername:8080/tfs/[Collection]/[Project]/_workitems#_a=edit&id=[ID]
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had to do this, you have to set your web access permissions in the Control Panel online, to Full instead of Standard:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj159364.aspx